# vue-meta doesn't show meta tags in page source

Tags: vue.js, vue-meta

I'm using vue CLI and vue router.
I've imported vue-meta and meta tags doesn't show up. only page title works and shows up in page source.

Not using NUXT. Not sure if vue-meta only works with NUXT?

Below is my code. please advise. Thanks

```
 metaInfo:{
    title:'Page title..',
    meta:[
        {name: 'application-name', content: 'App Name' },
        { name: 'description', content: 'some description abouthe page', id: 'desc' }
    ]
```

},

Comment: You need either server-side rendering (e.g. Nuxt.js) or prerendering for that.

Comment: @str Thanks. that's what i was afraid of..

Comment: Hi @user3260392 what is your solution for this